# Is hosting images in one's site considered "data out" by Azure?

Tags: image, jpeg, azure-web-app-service

I asked a question here on the msdn forum:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/a291718c-07f3-4c7b-8e7e-932f6875b66e/why-are-my-two-web-sites-unavailable?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

...but that place is like a ghost town compared to StackOverflow.

Of the two sites in question that I have hosted on azurewebsites.net, one contains only links to images stored elsewhere, and they are small (images of amazon products), but the other one has a couple of dozen jpgs served directly by the site.

Is the serving of these images the reason why Microsoft says, "*This site is currently not available...*"?

According to the answer at the link above, I "*...have exceeded the data egress (data out) quota...*"

Notwithstanding the fact that I thought an egress was a fledgling eagle of the female "persuasion," I am wondering if this is what is really considered "data out" from my app, or is there maybe something else going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images are served through your Azure Websites IIS (as compared to linking to external images as you described it) then this will count towards your "data out" quota.

The [documentation](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-monitor-websites/) of data out as

> a measure of the amount of data sent from web sites running in Shared mode to their clients in the current quota interval

does not distinguish between dynamic/static content, mime-types or something similar so all transferred bytes count.

Please also take note of [this discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/8f3eaf37-65ae-44ba-b7da-65f320caa326/data-out-quota-considers-ftp-transfers-?forum=websitesvirtualmachinesonwinserver) where Microsoft seems to confirm that **Data out quota considers FTP transfers** which might also add to a problematic quota situation you might be having.